# Object methods in ObjC documentation that don't have plus or minus signs

Tags: objective-c

What are the methods in class references that have no + or - symbol? Some methods have a plus sign, and these are class methods, and the ones with the minus sign are instance methods.

One example is the [`NSString` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/capitalizedString)

```
capitalizedString
```

What are these functions?

Comment: FYI - the `+` are "class methods", not "object functions", and the `-` are "instance methods", not "object instance functions".

Comment: You know, it does say "property" right next to the title of the method in the Apple docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are Objective-C [properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

You can see this if you look at the definition in NSString.h:

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *capitalizedString;
```